# Query ParseUser Swift 3 Error

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, swift3

I get the Error : Cannot convert value of type '([PFObject]?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type '([PFObject]?, Error?) -> Void?

The Code that is causing this error is found Below.

```
findUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }


    return cell
}
```

I have been stuck with this error for the past few days and I can't seem to locate a working solution on I found was to switch anyObject with PFObject which I did but I was getting the same error. I'm trying to query the userName and display it in a UITableView Cell.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the meat of the error message lies:

Cannot convert value of type '([PFObject]?, **NSError**?) -> Void' to expected argument type '([PFObject]?, **Error**?) -> Void?

Swift 3.0 introduced the `Error` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/error), which is what is catching you here.

Try the following change and see if it resolves your problem:

```
findUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in // Changes NSError to Error
        if error == nil{
            let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: It changed the error to: Cannot convert value of type '[PFObject]?' to type 'NSArray' in coercion

Comment: @Jbarfield101 When I first encountered this issue, I had a similar problem that required me to fix a chain of events. From the error, you probably define [PFObject] as ab NSArray at some point, but it is now returning an Array.

Comment: So the best course of action would be to declare as an NSArray again?

Comment: @Jbarfield101 You can try to do that, but sometimes it is best to bring the app into compliance with Swift 3.0 by removing those. That decision is up to you / your team.

Comment: So where I have the array to NSArray is like this:                                      ` let array:NSArray = self.partyData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects as NSArray
                self.partyData = NSMutableArray(array: array)
                
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            
            }`   how should I replace this into Compliance?